# Convert coordinates between parent/child UIView after CGAffineTransform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, cgaffinetransform

Before I go into doing everything by hand I would like to ask if there is some help to get from the framework.

I have a UIView that holds another UIView with a map. The parent UIView holds some legends for the map. Initially I define some coordinates in the map view. e.g. (100, 40), and place a piece of graphics there in the parent view (like a tack in google maps etc.). The parent view and the child view are both 300x200 and have the same origin. This means that (100, 40) is the same point in both views.

Now I zoom and move the child UIView(the map) using CGAffineTransform and the coordinate (100, 40) is now situated somewhere else. The parent view is effectively a mask here.

**Can I use the CGAffineTransform Matrix or another part of the framework to calculate and inform the parent view where to place the tack now that the point has moved?**

*i.e. (100, 400) in the child view compared to (100, 40) in the parent view, what does it compare to after the transformation?*

Thank you for suggestions or help given.

The animation of the child UIView

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; 
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.8f, 1.8f);
    worldMap.transform = transform;
    worldMap.bounds.origin = newPos;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

UIView's `-convertPoint:toView:` and `-convertPoint:fromView:` should work for you.

Comment: Costique is correct, there's no need to do the matrix math yourself.  You have the whole view hierarchy system to help you.

Comment: answer is correct but I'd be great If you explained toView fromView differences

Comment: toView converts from the calling views space to the destination views space.

Comment: fromView converts from the source views space to the calling views space